# Invalid character in bcp

Tags: c#, sql, bcp

I'm trying to call a BCP command from c#.I'm building the command within the c# code, and am getting an error. Here is the BCP command as I'm building it:

```
string.Format("bcp \"EXEC {0} {1}\" queryout \"{2}\" -c -t\"\0\" -S {3} -U {4} -P {5}", spName, filterList, path, server, user, password);
```

Here is the command after formatting:

```
"bcp \"EXEC StatisticsByType @Date='1/1/2013'\" queryout \"\\\\Server\\Folder\\MagicWords.txt\" -c -t\"\0\" -S server.com -U userName -P password"
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
{"Incorrect syntax near 'queryout'.\r\n'.' is an invalid name because it contains a NULL character or an invalid unicode character."}
```

I'm assuming it has something to do with how .Net is escaping the ". Would anyone know the proper way to pass those quotation marks around, or if thats even the issue?

**EDIT:** I ran the BCP command in question from the powershell ISE. It threw an "Unable to open BCP host data-file" error. So I changed the queryout server name to it's mapped network drive name, and It worked. However, doing the same thing in C# yielded no change.

Comment: Do you have a CRLF in either your query string or the file path?  It looks to me like you might have an embedded CRLF and maybe a special character showing up as a '.'

Comment: I don't think I do. It's all written on a single line in Visual Studio. I'm looking now to see if I can verify this.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is the delimiter. The sequence `-t\"\0\"` translates to a NULL character between quotes. You might try replacing `\0` with another delimeter like `,` or `;`. If you do want the NULL character as a delimiter you should insert `-t\\0` in your string.

Comment: I changed the null delimiter to \\0 and the error message changed! Progress! Now, though, it just says "{"Incorrect syntax near 'queryout'."}".